# Why is it impossible to use method references to `suspend` functions in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

I have a list of `Job` instances which I want to cancel at some point after launch. This looks as follows:

```
val jobs = arrayListOf<Job>()
//launch and add jobs...
jobs.forEach { it.cancelAndJoin() } // cancels the jobs and waits for completion
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use a method reference here. The reason: `cancelAndJoin` is a `suspend` function, as the compiler complains:

```
jobs.forEach (Job::cancelAndJoin)
```

*"Error:(30, 24) Kotlin: Unsupported [Callable references to suspend functions]"*

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPD:** This has already been implemented in Kotlin 1.3.x. Taking a callable reference to a suspending function gives you an instance of `KSuspendFunctionN` (`N` = 0, 1, ...). This type has its `invoke` operator defined as a suspending function, so that you can invoke such a callable reference suspending a coroutine in the same way as a direct invocation would.

---

Basically, supporting this requires an additional portion of language design and does not simply come bundled with coroutines.

Why is it non-trivial? Because when you take a callable reference of an ordinary function e.g. `String::reversed`, you get something like a `KFunction1<String, String>`. If you could do the same with a `suspend` function, what would you expect to get?

If it's the same `KFunctionN<...>`, then there's an obvious problem that you can pass it around where an ordinary function is expected and call it, violating the rule that `suspend` functions can only be called inside coroutines (where the compiler transforms their call sites).

So, it should be something more specific. (I'm currently only speculating, without any idea of actual design attempts) It could be, for example, a `SuspendKFunctionN<...>`, with its `invoke(...)` being a suspending function, or it could (less likely) be a special notation only for passing a function reference where a `suspend (T) -> R` is expected, but anyway, a feature like this requires thorough design to be future-proof.

Comment: Alright, I'll wait for that then ;-) Thanks, Sergey

Comment: @s1m0nw1, some work in progress on this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21972

Comment: @hotkey, that ticket has already been closed and only isSuspend was added as a result. I didn't find any work-in-progress based on your suggestion. Any reference?

Comment: @yuranos87, callable references to suspend functions have been implemented. They are typed as `KSuspendFunctionN`, which can be invoked via the `invoke` operator convention, giving a suspending call.

Comment: @hotkey, can you also provide an example. I'm trying to pass fun reference inside Flow.fold() like so: .all().asFlow().fold(emptySet(), ::reducer) and I get a compilation error(found KFunction2)

Comment: I see it being references for resolution https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/descriptors/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/builtins/functions/FunctionClassDescriptor.kt but I can't find KSuspendFunctionN class itself.

Answer (score 2):

These helpers currently lack in Kotlin Standard library, but you can implement your own.

For example:

```
suspend fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEachAsync(action: suspend (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    val list = this.map { e ->
        async(...) {
            action(e)
        }
    }
    list.forEach { it.await() }
}
```

However, what context to pass to async now depends on the threading model your service is using (i.e. do you want to do multi-threading or want to keep everything in a single thread).